# Please help this SQL query

Tags: sql

Tables:

```
Doctor(doctor_id, name, address, tel, specialty)

Patient(patient_id, name, numsecu, doctor_reference)

Visit(doctor, patient, date_visit)
```

The question is show the patients who have seen every specialty doctors.

I do this way but I don't know how to check that the patients have seen every specialty doctors.

```
select distinct p.nom, m.specialite
from patient p, visite v, medecin m
where p.patient_id = v.patient
and v.medecin = m.medecin_id
group by p.nom, m.specialite
```

Comment: First and formost, do not ever use that horrible implicit syntax again.It is a SQL antipattern!

Comment: @HLGEM can you tell me what you mean by antipattern? what syntax?

Comment: AN antipattern is a programming techiniwue that you in general should not use. IMplicit joins are one of them. this is the implicit join patient p, visite v, medecin m where p.patient_id = v.patient and v.medecin = m.medecin_id - so Joe's answer for how to explicit joins. And then read about them. There is no excuse for not kinowing this stuff if you query a database.

Answer (score 5):

Made a bit of an assumption here that "specialty doctors" are identified by a non-null `specialite` column in the `medecin` table.

**EDIT**: Added JOIN to `medecin` in the main query to filter the visits to only specialty doctors.

```
SELECT p.nom
    FROM patient p
        INNER JOIN visite v
            ON p.patient_id = v.patient
        INNER JOIN medicin m
            ON v.medecin = m.medecin_id
    WHERE m.specialite IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY p.nom
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.medecin_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                               FROM medecin 
                                               WHERE specialite IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: It helps to solve these issues if you break the problem down into parts. First you need to know the count of distinct specialties. Then you need to know the count of specialties the patient has visited. Then you need to compare the two numbers and see if they match. Thuis basically what Joe did here for you.

Comment: Thank you Joe but I don't know how to check the number of specialties that the patient has visited.